# Precompose multiple layers in OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have made an [Openlayers layer-spy example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/layer-spy.html), but with 5 layers added to the map. I want to be able to toggle between the different layers, and set them as "spy-layer" and background-layer with a dropDown or something. How is that possible?
All the examples I have seen, are only using 1 layer as "spy-layer" and 1 layer as background.

My experience with Openlayers is not that great, so please be kind to me! =)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two layers in the map, as in the ol3 `layer-spy` example. The first layer is the background layer. The second layer, which is above the first layer, is the spy layer.

And to change the background layer you can use:

```js
map.getLayers().setAt(0, newBackgroundLayer);
```

To change the spy layer:

And to change the background layer you can use:

```js
map.getLayers().setAt(1, newSpyLayer);
```